# Is it possible to trace / watch the values of a session in the aspx webpage itself?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm debugging a project website with several classes; while most of the code is handled in C#, are several if statements in the HTML-based pages, which uses sessions to update itself.

So, for example, I press a button, and the HTML-based page calls out a Javascript function, which then calls out a C# function.

```
<input class='buttonbrowse' type="button" name="btnShiftDate" value="..." <%=(requestApplicationForm.Paycode==null ? " disabled=disabled" : "")%> onclick="javascript:SelectExcessHrs_time();" id="Button1" />
```

This function does a lot of calculation, and stores all the variables and whatnot in a class 'paycodeform'.

At the end of the code, this is returned:

```
Session["SubsidyApplicationForm"] = paycodeform;
```

Back in the HTML Page, this happens:

```
<%if(requestApplicationForm.Excessdatepunch!=null) {%>
```

Etc., etc. Basically, there are in-line C# codes (is that what one would call them?) embedded in the HTML page. A LOT of codes. And they do some sort of filtering through the paycodeform.

Excessdatepunch is an array, which contains values at the time paycodeform was passed back into the session. Unfortunately, somewhere along the HTML code, the Excessdatepunch array is cleared, and re-supplied with default values - running through the long list of codes is frustrating, and to complicate matters further, this error doesn't happen often.

So as with the title, I'd like to ask if there's someway to monitor these in-line C# codes. I know that placing a breakpoint there won't work, while placing a watch on the session doesn't exactly give me the inner workings such as the values inside the Excessdatepunch array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* break the code execution in ASPX by using `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()`. You can also write to the trace and debug listeners. Try debugging the following code sample:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        This is some HTML. The current time is:
        <%
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            Session["CurrentTime"] = DateTime.Now;
        %>
    </div>
    <%
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(Session["CurrentTime"]);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Session["CurrentTime"]);
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        Response.Write(Session["CurrentTime"]);
        Response.Write("<br/>");
    %>
    You should see the current date above this line.
</form>
```

If you want to have the trace output shown in the page, add the `Trace` attribute to the `<%@ Page %>` tag:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Trace="true" ... %>
```

References:

- [Walkthrough: Integrating ASP.NET Tracing with System.Diagnostics Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0ectfxd%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [How to: Enable Tracing for an ASP.NET Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94c55d08%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Curious, it doesn't allow me to hover over a variable and see what it does / contains. I was able to do that previously, albeit by breaking from the C# code, before jumping into the HTML code, after two dozen F10 button presses or so.

EDIT: I've removed the code I tried from above. I'm no longer able to hover over the in-line C# codes in the HTML. Yikes.